# How to find out time taken by Linux system for cold boot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I am trying to find out the time taken by a Linux machine to boot up after a cold reboot. Looks like the `uptime` command or `/proc/uptime` gives you the time since init process is up. This does not take into account the time taken by kernel to load into memory, loader and firmware startup time (like `systems-analyze` does). I can not use `systems-analyze` since, if I use that, I will have to wait for all systemd services to be up. For the same reason, even 'bootchart' is ruled out.This is because I am going to have to collect the boot time through a systemd service (that is doing a bunch of other things).

Any idea how I can get this information?

Answer (score 2):

**With a stopwatch.** Much of the process will happen before the system is ready to time stuff.

You will also have to define what you mean by booted: Ready to login via X, ready to login via console, web-server responding to requests …

Also you should not trust the system under test, to test its self. (I once was trouble shooting a system, that claimed to be faster than what was possible. It turned out, that it was slowing down the clock.)

Comment: In long past days I would wait for a HP9000 K400 series machine to boot.  It would spend almost 30 minutes in its own variation of BIOS checks because it would check every byte of memory (and disable bad RAM chips) and so on.  One the hardware had completed the self checks, the OS loaded pretty quickly :-)

Answer (score 0):

`/var/log/boot.msg`

it will have text like

```
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.0.101-108.84-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc     version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP Fri Nov 30 15:57:27 UTC 2018 (7a72692)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=dev000:\EFI\SUSE\vmlinuz-    3.0.101-108.84-default root=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000cca070168a20-part2  splash=verbose showopts
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Using 'eager' FPU context switches.
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 00000000000a0000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000792de000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000792de000 - 00000000798f4000 (reserved)
```

then

```
[    4.967393] Brought up 128 CPUs
[    4.967400] Total of 128 processors activated (512000.20 BogoMIPS).
[    5.377931] devtmpfs: initialized
[    5.420574] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region at 79a38000 (5976064 bytes)
[    5.421208] print_constraints: dummy:
[    5.421243] Time: 20:15:03  Date: 01/22/19
[    5.421817] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    5.422067] ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
[    5.422073] ACPI: bus type pci registered
```

ending with

```
[   14.053705] igb 0000:42:00.3: added PHC on eth3
[   14.066858] igb 0000:42:00.3: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
[   14.080159] igb 0000:42:00.3: eth3: (PCIe:5.0Gb/s:Width x4) 0c:c4:7a:3a:51:33
[   14.093493] igb 0000:42:00.3: eth3: PBA No: 010A00-000
[   14.106628] igb 0000:42:00.3: Using MSI-X interrupts. 8 rx queue(s), 8 tx queue(s)
[   14.800728] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[   14.814242] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.25.0-ioctl (2012-07-25) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[   15.254103] loop: module loaded
[   15.634412] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, large block/inode numbers, no debug enabled
[   15.648644] SGI XFS Quota Management subsystem
[   15.661127] XFS (sda1): Mounting Filesystem
[   15.790512] XFS (sda1): Ending clean mount
[   15.802635] XFS (sdb1): Mounting Filesystem
[   15.886148] XFS (sdb1): Ending clean mount
[   15.898303] XFS (sdd1): Mounting Filesystem
[   16.010051] XFS (sdd1): Ending clean mount
[   17.567752] fuse init (API version 7.16)
Kernel logging (ksyslog) stopped.
Kernel log daemon terminating.

Waiting for device /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000cca070168a20-part2 to appear:  ok
fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
[/sbin/fsck.ext3 (1) -- /] fsck.ext3 -a -C0 /dev/sdc2
myhostname: clean, 1172494/36618240 files, 42233936/146465024 blocks
fsck succeeded. Mounting root device read-write.
```

So 17.56 seconds until handoff where linux root partition is mounted and the kernel boots.

Realize this is not the entire *boot* process to where all services in linux is running.  For that find the first timestamp in `/var/log/boot.msg` after the handoff, then find the last timestamp where you can reasonably conclude the system has fully booted: firewall started, ssh service started, maybe the best is GDM running.

My first timestamp shows 15:15:06.x
Last timestamp in file, after i automatically start a license manager, shows 15:15:53.x.  Timestamp having `smartd start exits with status 0` is at 15:15:43.x followed by `SuSEfirewall2_setup start' exits with status 0` at 15:15:44.x.

so 17.5 seconds + 47 seconds = 64.5 seconds total in my case.  And that typically matches my watch... realize all this is happening after the BIOS/EFI has taken at about 2 minutes, then goes through an LSI Raid controller starting up RAID-5 of 15 disks another 2 minutes.  So the total time you care about can vary greatly and will be dependent on what hardware there is if your definition of time taken from cold boot is when you push the power on button.  But for the time taken by the linux kernel you can usually figure it out from boot.msg.

Comment: I could not find /var/log/boot.msg but found that information in /var/log/kern.log. Your answer gave me enough hints to get my job done. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make a video with your smartphone aimed at the monitor. That will be accurate to 1/*n* seconds, where *n* is the number of frames per second the video is recorded at.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UEFI firmware that includes support for the ACPI FPDT table, and your kernel includes the `CONFIG_ACPI_FPDT` build-time option, then in `/sys/firmware/acpi/fpdt/boot`, you may find information on how much time the firmware and the bootloader took at start-up. In the neighboring directories, there can be timing information on suspend and resume operations too.

From the [patch that introduced the support for the FPDT table](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-acpi/patch/20210129061548.13448-1-rui.zhang@intel.com/):

```
> +               ACPI Firmware Performance Data Table (FPDT) provides
> +               information for firmware performance data for system boot,
> +               S3 suspend and S3 resume. This sysfs entry contains the
> +               performance data retrieved from the FPDT.
> +
> +               boot:
> +                       firmware_start_ns: Timer value logged at the beginning
> +                               of firmware image execution. In nanoseconds.
> +                       bootloader_load_ns: Timer value logged just prior to
> +                               loading the OS boot loader into memory.
> +                               In nanoseconds.
> +                       bootloader_launch_ns: Timer value logged just prior to
> +                               launching the currently loaded OS boot loader
> +                               image. In nanoseconds.
> +                       exitbootservice_start_ns: Timer value logged at the
> +                               point when the OS loader calls the
> +                               ExitBootServices function for UEFI compatible
> +                               firmware. In nanoseconds.
> +                       exitbootservice_end_ns: Timer value logged at the point
> +                               just prior to the OS loader gaining control
> +                               back from the ExitBootServices function for
> +                               UEFI compatible firmware. In nanoseconds.
> +               suspend:
> +                       suspend_start_ns: Timer value recorded at the previous
> +                               OS write to SLP_TYP upon entry to S3. In
> +                               nanoseconds.
> +                       suspend_end_ns: Timer value recorded at the previous
> +                               firmware write to SLP_TYP used to trigger
> +                               hardware entry to S3. In nanoseconds.
> +               resume:
> +                       resume_count: A count of the number of S3 resume cycles
> +                               since the last full boot sequence.
> +                       resume_avg_ns: Average timer value of all resume cycles
> +                               logged since the last full boot sequence,
> +                               including the most recent resume. In nanoseconds.
> +                       resume_prev_ns: Timer recorded at the end of the previous
> +                               platform runtime firmware S3 resume, just prior to
> +                               handoff to the OS waking vector. In nanoseconds.
```

I believe this is where `systemd-analyze` gets its firmware startup, loader and kernel loading timings, too.

Basically, take the value of `exitbootservice_end_ns`, subtract the value of `firmware_start_ns` from it, and you'll have the amount of time that passed between the CPU powering up and the Linux kernel starting up.

Note that if you have a server-grade system with a dedicated management processor, it is common that the management processor will begin running as soon as the system is plugged into a powered wall socket, but the main CPU won't be able to power on until the management processor has completed initialization, which can take a minute or two. On the other hand, such a management processor will usually provide plenty of logs with useful timestamps on its own.